# error: c code: expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c, windows, expression

I have two different structs in c file, struct A and B:

```
typedef Struct _A
{
   float arr[4];
}A;

typedef struct _B
{
   float const x;
   float const y;
}B;

 A* objA = (A*)malloc(sizeof(A));
 B* objB = (B*)malloc(sizeof(B));
```

what I need to do is assign arr values with values from struct B

```
 objA->arr = {objB->x, objB->y, objB->x, objB->x};  /// getting an error here : expression must be a modifiable lvalue.
```

I have memcpy so far, but that ends in another error "expression expected".
is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign to an array directly.  You'll need to either assign to each member individually:

```
objA->arr[0] = objB->x;
objA->arr[1] = objB->y;
objA->arr[2] = objB->x;
objA->arr[3] = objB->x;
```

Or use `memcpy` with a compound literal as the source:

```
memcpy(objA->arr, (float[4]){objB->x,objB->y,objB->x,objB->x}, sizeof(float[4]));
```

Comment: @PPp Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.